# Android : Samsung Galaxy Tabs and Android 2.2 Devices Showing GPS date 1 Day Advance from 1st jan 2012

Tags: android, gps, galaxy-tab, nmea

I have the Galaxy tab GT-P1000 7 inch with firmware version 2.3.3 and Phones running Android 2.2. In both versions when ever I am trying to get the time from GPS, its showing 1 day advance from 1st jan 2012. Same code is working fine on Samsung, LG and Motorola Phones.

The Sample code for the App is,

```
package com.vxceed.dateTime;


import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SampleDateTimeActivity extends Activity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private  TextView tv;
    String varTime="";

    /**
     * Location Listener 
     */
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(SampleDateTimeActivity.this,"GPS off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            setCurrentLocation(location);

        }
    };



    private void setCurrentLocation(Location location) {

          varTime=String.valueOf(location.getTime());

    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        locationManager=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);

         tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }


     public void refreshTime(View v)
     {
        String currentGPSTime="";
        currentGPSTime=varTime;
        if(currentGPSTime.compareTo("")==0)
        {
            tv.setText("Time Not Available");
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(new Long(currentGPSTime));

            long currentDeviceTime=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

            Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal2.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE)-1,cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            long currentGPSTime_less_one_Day=cal2.getTimeInMillis();

            tv.setText( "GPSTIME:"+cal.getTime().toString() +" \n GPS_TIME_in_Millis:"+varTime+"\nDevice_Time_in_millis:"+String.valueOf(currentDeviceTime) +"\nGPS Time -1 day:"+String.valueOf(currentGPSTime_less_one_Day));
        }
     }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationManager != null && locationListener != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            locationManager = null;
        }
    }


}
```

I have searched the Google and then referring the NMEA official document I figure out How to Use the NMEA data. Here is the Working Code for the NMEA listener:

```
NmeaListener nmeaListener = new NmeaListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {

            parse(nmea);
        }
    };


    private boolean parse(String strNMEA) {

        // Discard the sentence if its checksum does not match our calculated
        // checksum
        boolean bStatus = false;
        try {
            if (!IsValid(strNMEA)) {

                return false;
            }
            String[] sArrNMEA = strNMEA.split(",");
            String strNMEAType = sArrNMEA[0];
            if (strNMEAType.equals("$GPRMC")) {

                bStatus = ParseGPRMC(sArrNMEA);
            } else {

                bStatus = false;
            }

            sArrNMEA = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return bStatus;

    }

    private boolean ParseGPRMC(String[] sArrNMEA) {

        boolean result = false;
        try {
            if (sArrNMEA.length > 9) {
                int Hr = 0;
                int Mins = 0;
                int Secs = 0;

                if (!sArrNMEA[1].equals("")) {

                    Hr = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[1].substring(0, 2));
                    Mins = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[1].substring(2, 4));

                    if (sArrNMEA[1].length() > 6) {

                        Secs = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[1].substring(4, 6));
                    } else {
                        Secs = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[1].substring(4));
                    }

                }
                if (!sArrNMEA[9].equals("")) {
                    int Day = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[9].substring(0, 2));
                    int Month = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[9].substring(2, 4));
                    if (Month > 0) {
                        Month = Month - 1;
                    }
                    int Year = Integer.parseInt(sArrNMEA[9].substring(4));
                    Year = 2000 + Year;

                    if (!sArrNMEA[1].equals("")) {

                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                                .getTimeZone("UTC"));
                        cal.set(Year, Month, Day, Hr, Mins, Secs);

                        nmeaTime = String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis());

                    }

                }



                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return result;

    }

        private boolean IsValid(String strNMEA) {
        // Compare the characters after the asterisk to the calculation
        strNMEA = strNMEA.replace("\r", "");
        strNMEA = strNMEA.replace("\n", "");
        return strNMEA.substring(0, strNMEA.length())
                .substring(strNMEA.indexOf("*") + 1)
                .equalsIgnoreCase(GetChecksum(strNMEA));
    }

 private String GetChecksum(String strNMEA) {
    // Loop through all chars to get a checksum

    int Checksum = 0;
    try {
        char ch = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < strNMEA.length(); i++) {
            ch = strNMEA.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '$') {
                // Ignore the dollar sign
            } else if (ch == '*') {
                // Stop processing before the asterisk
                break;
            } else {
                // Is this the first value for the checksum?
                if (Checksum == 0) {
                    // Yes. Set the checksum to the value
                    Checksum = (byte) ch;
                } else {
                    // No. XOR the checksum with this character's value
                    Checksum = Checksum ^ (byte) ch;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    // Return the checksum formatted as a two-character hexadecimal
    return Integer.toHexString(Checksum);
}
```

Comment: I have solved the Above issue, Use NMEA location listener in Android. It will give the Correct GPS time.

Comment: On the three devices that I tested the NMEA location listener, the date given by the listener was always tomorrow's date.

Comment: You can use the Following Code for  NMEA Listener

Comment: I am just wondering: if it shows one day AHEAD, could I just check if `receivedLocationTimestamp > new Date().getTime()` ? if it returned `true` I would subtract 24h (as milliseconds) from `receivedLocationTimestamp`. Do you think it could work in longer term? (@MiG62)

Comment: @ShashikantSingh How do you implement method `GetChecksum()`?

Comment: Here is the full code with GetChecksum() function implementation

Comment: Is it Android bug or Samsung bug?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be affecting all stock Samsung firmwares, i am logging a concern with Samsung about this. It seems to be isolated to Samsung devices. So if you can test on another device, or install custom firmware. both of those have worked for me. and your code looks good, nothing wrong there, this is a firmware issue

EDIT: I have contacted the Korean Engineers - they have said they weren't aware of the problem but have patched and it should be fixed in the latest update for the SGS and other affected products. (unless of course that device hasn't had an update for a while - so not sure about the SGT) They have said the problem lies with the devices using Broadcomm chips...so yeah

Use the above code. it seems to work for me will have to check it on a few other devices but yeah

Comment: I manage 92 devices of various models of Samsung and HTC. Among these devices, the problem is restricted to those with a Hummingbird processor. I note that some versions of the Samsung Galaxy Tab use a Hummingbird processor. Not sure whether yours is among them.

Comment: That's very interesting. I wonder why the firmware is doing this on only devices with that processor. Custom firmware does fix this issue, but Samsung needs to put out a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Samsung were hoping that it was a leap year issue which would just go away after March 1st, 2012.

Sorry to disappoint - but it hasn't!  We have been seeing this problem with the app PhoneTrack installed on Samsung phones since January 1st and it is still there today.

Hopefully, Samsung will now act responsibly and issue updates for all devices affected by this GPS driver bug.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this bug on my Nexus S running Android 4.0.3 (annoyingly causing a whole bunch of data to be incorrectly timestamped).

I was upgraded to 4.0.4 yesterday and this seems to have fixed the issue. Not sure if there is a plan to issue fixes to previous Android versions.

A real howler of a bug though...

Comment: could you please take a look at my comment (under question)? I am wondering if this approach could work as well (instead of this NMEA thing).

Comment: tks for sharing, checking it. What an annoying bug

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me and I replaced `IsValid(String strNMEA)` method with this function:

```
private boolean checksum(String strNMEA)
    {
        int checksum = 0;

        strNMEA = strNMEA.replace("\r", "");
        strNMEA = strNMEA.replace("\n", "");

        String strChecksum = strNMEA.substring(strNMEA.indexOf("*") + 1);

        String str = strNMEA.substring(1, strNMEA.indexOf("*"));

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            checksum = checksum ^ str.charAt(i);
        }

        return checksum == Integer.valueOf(strChecksum, 16);

    }
```