# Java, android, get atomic time from itnernet server

Tags: java, android, time, ntp

i trying to synchronize two apps.
How can i get the server time of any server with an accuracy up to 1ms? or maybe just 10ms?

i tried this some SNTP Clients, but they give me only my destination time or only with an accuracy up to 1s.

Pls help.

Comment: Perhaps syncing via GPS-Time is an option for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210264/sync-android-devices-via-gps-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your SNTP client to follow a time server out there. There are 2 ways to sync your time. SLAM, or SLEW.

SLAM, just takes the server time and throws it on the client.

SLEW, takes the server time and corrects your client time, over the next few minutes.

In your case, I suggest that, as your application loads, use SLAM.

In the uxix, netware world, there were utilities like `ntpdate` for slaming, and `ntpd` for slewing.

SNTP is the way to go, these clients have been around for like 15 years now, so its very stable. Infact new development stopped like 8 years back. So it ought to be very stable. Just take more time and configure it right.

[sntp android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java)

Comment: There is also a way to get ntpd to slam when it loads and slew later. I just give so much information so that you get confidence that sntp works :).