# Getting accurate time from the internet

Tags: android, ntp

I am trying to get time from the internet and do not want want to use the device time.
I am doing the following sntp client request for time, but as expected the time received is not accurate due to request - response time. How do I overcome the latency and get a maximum variation of +/- 20ms??

```
 Long time=0; 
    while (true) {
     SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
     if (client.requestTime("time-a.nist.gov",6000)) {
       long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                        - client.getNtpTimeReference();
       Log.d("Time Difference", time-now+"");
       time=now;
       Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
    }
```

The log file is as follows:

```
- 02-10 23:27:16.125: E/Time Difference(15566): -5804
- 02-10 23:27:21.449: E/Time Difference(15566): -5272
- 02-10 23:27:26.774: E/Time Difference(15566): -5358
- 02-10 23:27:32.206: E/Time Difference(15566): -5365
- 02-10 23:27:37.528: E/Time Difference(15566): -5328
- 02-10 23:27:43.056: E/Time Difference(15566): -5429
- 02-10 23:27:48.892: E/Time Difference(15566): -5694
- 02-10 23:27:54.730: E/Time Difference(15566): -5972
- 02-10 23:28:00.563: E/Time Difference(15566): -5679
- 02-10 23:28:06.096: E/Time Difference(15566): -5686
```

The time difference is expected to be constant 5000 at perfect execution.

Comment: "The time difference is expected to be constant 5000 at perfect execution" -- Android is not a RTOS. Furthermore, `sleep()` is not accurate "at perfect execution" -- all it does is arrange for the thread to be available for scheduling after that number of milliseconds. When the thread *will* start executing instructions is up to the OS, and it will depend upon what else is going on with the device.

Comment: So can I assume variations in my values are due to the sleep() and not latency?

Comment: I am saying that relying on `sleep()` to be accurate is a flawed approach to your testing.

Comment: Check out [this question][1]. There are several methods listed


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android

Answer (score 0):

> How do I overcome the latency and get a maximum variation of +/- 20ms??

I don't know about +/- 20ms, but assuming the Android device in question has GPS, you could could get the time from the GPS sub-system, as GPS time is (has to be) very precise. You can use [`requestSingleUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) for that as discussed in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210264/sync-android-devices-via-gps-time).

Comment: "did you manage to sync with GPS? As far as I know, Location.getTime provides the system-time, when the location update was obtained, i.e. no GPS clock is involved on this layer".  This is one of the answer and as i said I dont want system-time

Comment: @user1980743: Do we know that answer is correct? But yeah, it does seem like even if the GPS clock is involved, it's still going to be a translation of that against the device's current date/time, which may not be helpful... But if you just need 5000ms spacing, don't use `getTime`, use [`getElapsedRealtimeNanos`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getElapsedRealtimeNanos()). I didn't say "use `getTime`". :-)

Comment: no its not about 5000ms, 5000ms is for my testing. I need a reference clock over two or more devices to be same.

Answer (score 0):

`client.requestTime` is a network operation. I can never take less than a certain amount of time, over which you have absolutely no control.

The variations you observe are dictated by fluctuations in connexion time, network quality...

Comment: So there is no way of getting accurate time on the android device?

Comment: `client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference()` is quite accurate. NtpTimeReference is, IIUC, the time of the system when the time was update from the network. `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                        - client.getNtpTimeReference()` tells you how close you are from that moment.

Answer (score -1):

In java. For sleep I use this bit.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long current = start;
while(current - start < 5000){
    current = System.currentTimeMillis();     
}
```

that 5 lines is my "Sleep" code. try using that and see what results you get.

Comment: no improvement in the result                                                              02-11 00:09:46.519: E/Time Difference(17610): -5716
02-11 00:09:51.950: E/Time Difference(17610): -5378
02-11 00:09:57.374: E/Time Difference(17610): -5460
02-11 00:10:02.850: E/Time Difference(17610): -5523
02-11 00:10:08.439: E/Time Difference(17610): -5575
02-11 00:10:13.783: E/Time Difference(17610): -5269
02-11 00:10:19.184: E/Time Difference(17610): -5438

Comment: Are u trying to get results like 5020 or less?

Comment: I just want the time received to be consistent.

Comment: So ya. Nothing wrong with your code. It just the network that messing you up. OR find a better / faster server or build one on your computer.